# Android Media Playback Service Pause/Play

Tags: android, android-service, android-mediaplayer

I'm not very experienced in Android, but I'm trying to make a Media Playback Service. My Start and Stop are working, but Pause/Play aren't. I've tried many different ways, but always unsuccessful.

When I pause and press play again, it starts from 0 or give me an error:

```
11-02 18:50:57.971    2043-2043/? E/MediaPlayer﹕ start called in state 2
11-02 18:50:57.971    2043-2043/? E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (-38, 0)
11-02 18:50:57.975    2043-2043/? E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (-38,0)
```

Here is my Main Activity:

```
    package my.package;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnStartSvc;
    Button btnStopSvc;
    Button btnPauseSvc;
    Button btnResumeSvc;
    private static final String TAG = "MyService";
    private static final String TAG_LINK = "link";
    private static final String TAG_PAUSE = "PAUSE";
    private static final String TAG_STOP = "STOP";
    private static final String TAG_ACTION = "ACTION";
    private String pause = "pause";
    private String stop = "stop";
    private String link;
    Context context;

    boolean playPause;
    private boolean initialStage = true;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnStartSvc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStartSvc);
        btnStopSvc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStopSvc);
        btnPauseSvc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPauseSvc);
        btnResumeSvc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnResumeSvc);

        link = "http://stats.jovemnerd.com.br/nc489alta.mp3";
        context = this;

        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();


        btnStartSvc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startSvc();
            }
        });

        btnStopSvc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                stopSvc();
            }
        });

        btnPauseSvc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                pauseSvc();
            }
        });

        btnResumeSvc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                resumeSvc();
            }
        });

    }

    public void resumeSvc(){
        Intent i = new Intent(this,MyService.class);
        i.putExtra("action", "my.package.action.RESUME");
        startService(i);
    }

    public void pauseSvc(){
        Intent i = new Intent(this,MyService.class);
        i.putExtra("action", "my.package.action.PAUSE");
        startService(i);
    }

    public void startSvc(){
        Log.d(TAG, "Start");
        Intent i = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        i.putExtra("action", "my.package.action.PLAY");
        i.putExtra(TAG_LINK, link);
        startService(i);
    }

    public void stopSvc(){
                initialStage = true;
                playPause=false;
        Log.d(TAG, "Stop");
        Intent i = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        stopService(i);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Service:

```
package my.package;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

public class MyService extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {

    private static final String ACTION_PLAY = "my.package.action.PLAY";
    private static final String ACTION_PAUSE = "my.package.action.PAUSE";
    private static final String ACTION_STOP = "my.package.action.STOP";
    private static final String ACTION_RESUME = "my.package.action.RESUME";

    private static final String TAG = "MyService";
    private static final String TAG_LINK = "link";
    private static final String TAG_PAUSE = "PAUSE";
    private static final String TAG_STOP = "STOP";
    private static final String TAG_ACTION = "ACTION";

    private String url = "";
    private String teste = "http://stats.jovemnerd.com.br/nc489alta.mp3";
    private String action;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = null;
    WifiManager.WifiLock wifiLock;

    boolean playPause;
    private boolean initialStage = true;

    public MyService() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        teste = intent.getStringExtra("action");

        Log.d("Work: ", teste);

        if (intent.getStringExtra("action").equals(ACTION_PLAY)) {

            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

            mediaPlayer.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
            url = intent.getStringExtra(TAG_LINK);

            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

            mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);

            try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (!playPause) {
                //btnPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_white);
                if (initialStage) {
                    Log.d("PLAY", "PLAY");

                    mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

                    wifiLock = ((WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE))
                            .createWifiLock(WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL, "mylock");

                    wifiLock.acquire();
                } else if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    //seekBar.setMax((int) finalTime);
                }
                playPause = true;
                initialStage = false;
            }
        } else if (intent.getStringExtra("action").equals(ACTION_PAUSE)){
            Log.d("PAUSE", "PAUSE");
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                if(mediaPlayer != null) {
                    mediaPlayer.reset();
                    mediaPlayer.release();
                }
                playPause = false;
                initialStage = false;
                mediaPlayer = null;
            }
        } /*else if (intent.getStringExtra("action").equals(ACTION_RESUME)){
            if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }*/

        //url = intent.getStringExtra(TAG_LINK);
        /*mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mediaPlayer.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);*/

        Log.d(TAG, "Start Command");

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Player Started");
        mediaPlayer.start();
        initialStage = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        Log.d("Completed: ", "ok");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            mediaPlayer.release();
            Log.d(TAG, "Stop Command" + action);
        }
        wifiLock.release();
        initialStage = true;
        playPause = false;
    }


    public void pausePlayer(){
        if(mediaPlayer != null){
            mediaPlayer.reset();
            mediaPlayer.release();
            mediaPlayer = null;
    }}

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

}
```

Manifest:

```
<service
    android:name="my.package.MyService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true" >
</service>
```

*Service is inside `<Application>`

I hope you can help me. Thx.

Comment: I've found this comment at a youtube tutorial [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PQ7LBsaYcOk) : "You can implement a real Pause button by binding to the service and kicking off the Pause method of the MediaPlayer when the Pause button is pressed.  This requires you to save the song position in preferences in case Android decides to recoup resources by closing the activity, or the user exits." Any Idea?